# Natural Language Programming vs. Literate Programming

Tags: literate-programming

I can't see a difference between natural language programming and literate programming. If anyone explains, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Natural language programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming) is a system for expressing instructions to a computer in a form approximating a language humans write or speak.  NLP syntax structure usually resembles human-language sentence structure, in a form that might sound stilted to a native speaker, but which tends to read almost like the real language.  Many NLP implementations are focused on querying data stores rather than writing programs, but actual programming implementations also exist.

[Literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) is a system for simultaneously writing programs and writing about programs.  Unlike NLP, the code portions of a literate program are written in traditional programming languages.  The classic examples, for which the name was coined, are Donald Knuth's writings on the TeX typesetting system.  Published as his *Computers and Typesetting* series, the printed books are the result of processing his TeX literate program with a tool that extracts and formats only the descriptive portions.  Similarly, the compilable source code is the result of processing the same literate program with a tool that extracts and reorganizes the code portions.

Answer (score 3):

**A literate program** is an explanation of the program logic in a natural language, such as English, interspersed with snippets of macros and traditional source code. Macros in a literate source file are simply title-like or explanatory phrases in a human language that describe human abstractions created while solving the programming problem, and hiding chunks of code or lower-level macros. These macros are similar to the algorithms in pseudocode typically used in teaching computer science. These arbitrary explanatory phrases become precise new operators, created on the fly by the programmer, forming a meta-language on top of the underlying programming language.

The example is shown in following link

http://en.literateprograms.org/Insertion_sort_%28C%29

**Natural Language processing** deals with processing of natural text. Natural text can be simple english, french or any language sentence. It deals with processing of this sentence. This processing can involve steps like tokenization, Part of Speech tagging, stemming, Lemmatization, Sentiment Analysis etc. Basically It deals with getting the meaning out of any sentence with the help of programming
This link will give intro about NLP

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfoudtpBV68

Comment: The question wasn't about natural language *processing*, though.

Comment: It was about natural language **programming**. But thanks for useful explanations, links and your effort. +1 when I have 15 reputation :-)